# Python search multiple word in list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have Python list like this:

```
['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']
```

Now I want to search with multiple keywords in my list, e.g:

When I try to input the keyword **teacher** and **sales**

```
input keywords: teacher sales
```

it should return result like this:

- schoolteacher
- mathematics teacher
- salesperson
- sales manager

So far I have made a code like this:

```
job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']

def search_multiple_words(search_words):
    search_words = [search_words]

    for line in job_list:
        if any(word in line for word in search_words):
            print(line)

search_words = input("input keywords: ")
search_multiple_words(search_words)
```

But it just works when I input one keyword, not multiple keywords like example I gave above.

So, how to do that..?

Comment: Quite a lot of issue: 1. `input()` give you one string, you should have split the input search words into a list.  2. first 2 lines in `search_multiple_words()` seems not making any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager',
            'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']


def search_multiple_words(search_words):
    search_words = search_words.split(' ')

    out = [s for s in job_list if any(xs in s for xs in search_words)]
    print(out)


search_words = input("input words: ")
search_multiple_words(search_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find) method. This should work for you:

```
lis=['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']
str1 = ["teacher", "sales"]
x=[]
for y in lis:
    for string in str1:
        if y.find(string) != -1:
            x.append(y)
```

The above code was for **readability and understandability**. However, it can be **compressed** into a nice one-liner using list comprehensions like this:

```
x = [y for y in lis for string in str1 if y.find(string) != -1]
```

Both do the same thing and give the output as this

> ['salesperson', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics
>   teacher']

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

As Adrian Shum said, your input gives you a single string. You need to split it up first before feeding it to your function

```
job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']

def search_multiple_words(search_words):
    # Not neecssary anymore as you're feeding a list
    # search_words = [search_words]

    for line in job_list:
        if any(word in line for word in search_words):
            print(line)

search_words = input("input keywords: ").strip().split()
search_multiple_words(search_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 
            'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']

def search_multiple_words(search_words):
    search_words = [search_words]

    for line in job_list:
        if any(word in line for word in search_words):
            print(line)

search_words = input("input keywords: ").split(' ')
for w in search_words:
    search_multiple_words(w)
```

output:

```
input keywords: sales teacher
salesperson
sales manager
schoolteacher
mathematics teacher
```