# Javascript search multiple word in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a questions base on previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54818796/8070090).

There I'm using Python to do that, but now I want to convert the code to Javascript code.

So basically my questions there are, let's say I have an array like this:

```
job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']
```

And now I want to search with multiple keywords in my array, e.g:

When I try to input the keyword **teacher** and **sales**, it should return result like this:

- schoolteacher
- mathematics teacher
- salesperson
- sales manager

So, how to do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` and `some`:

```js
const job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher'];

const getJobs = (...words) => job_list.filter(s => words.some(w => s.includes(w)))
console.log(getJobs("teacher", "sales"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a regular expression that describes what you want and `filter` accordingly with [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```js
let job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']

let filtered = job_list.filter(job => /teacher|sales/.test(job))
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` like this:

```js
job_list = ['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']

console.log(job_list.filter(word => word.includes("teacher") || word.includes("sales")))
```

Complexity: O(N)